# woocommerce session key duplicate

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

Hi everyone, I am having an issue on and off with my sessions in woocommerce. My session_key shows 1 for all the sessions and when I refresh my page, it keeps adding more and more rows into the table.

I am suspecting it has something to do with my code that contains wc() or WC(), but I can't find clearer documentations on this section. Could anyone assist me ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The session_key field was not unique